# Angular 2 dynamic two-way binding

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to build a component that appends another component dynamically. As an example here is my parent class:

```
import { Component, ComponentRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/sample-component.component.html',
    selector: 'sample-component'
})
export class SampleComponent {

    @ViewChild('dynamicContent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    protected dynamicComponentTarget: ViewContainerRef;
    private currentComponent: ComponentRef<any>;
    private selectedValue: any;

    constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    }

    private appendComponent(componentType: any) {
        var factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
        this.currentComponent = this.dynamicComponentTarget.createComponent(factory);
    }
}
```

`sample-component.component.html:`

```
<div #dynamicContent></div>
```

It works fine with appending an element, but i have no idea about how to bind two-way dynamically, like i do in static components: `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Binding with dynamically added components is not supported.

You can use a shared service to communicate with dynamically added components (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)
or you can read/set imperatively using the `this.currentComponent` reference:

```ts
private appendComponent(componentType: any) {
    var factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
    this.currentComponent = this.dynamicComponentTarget.createComponent(factory);
    this.currentComponent.instance.value = this.selectedValue;
    this.currentComponent.instance.valueChange.subscribe(val => this.selectedValue = val);
}
```

Comment: Ok, then I think it's better to use `ControlValueAccessor` interface, but i'm not sure if any component, that provides construction like `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` inmplements this interface.
So the it can be used this way `this.currentComponent.instance.registerOnChange(this.valueChangeHandler);`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `ControlValueAccessor` implementation is required for `[(ngModel)]="..."` to work, but that's also an Angular2 binding and therefore not supported on dynamically added components.

Comment: could you please expand on this @GünterZöchbauer ? How does this.currentComponent.instance.value associate with the DOM input element inside of componentTypes template: ` ... ` in order to replace <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"> ? I would be most grateful if you could share a plunker.

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren it would need to be something like `<input [(ngModel)]="value" ...>` I think you then need to invoke change detection manually. Either using `this.currentInstance...` (don't remember details) or inject `this.cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` to the dynamically added component and call `this.currentComponent.instance.cdRef.detectChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround.

from the code posted above.

```
private appendComponent(componentType: any) {
 var factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
 this.currentComponent = this.dynamicComponentTarget.createComponent(factory);
 this.currentComponent.instance.value = this.selectedValue;
 this.currentComponent.instance.valueChange.subscribe(val => this.selectedValue = val);
```

}

Make dynamic variable as a Object and now assign it to the variable in parent component.

```
//at dynamically created component
export class DynamicComponent{
public bindedValue : Object = {
 value:''
 }
}

// at dynamic component template
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bindedValue.value"/>


//At parent component
this.currentComponent.instance.bindedValue= this.selectedValue;
```

Now bindedValue and selectedValue will have the same object reference. Both will hold the same value.