# Change attribute name

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, setattribute

I want to add a new attribute to an element. The catch is that the name of the attribute has invalid characters. Whitch again gives the wrong output. I work with Angular 7 and use the Render2 for this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService, private renderer: Renderer2, private elem: ElementRef) { }
...
```

This is the code:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(element, '[(dragulaModel)]', 'left');
```

Whitch gives this attribute output. It even set the name lowercase:

```
< ... dragulamodel="left" ... />
```

I would like it to be with the "invalid" characters:

```
< ... [(dragulaModel)]="left" ... />
```

Anyone have a solution for adding "invalid" characters to the attribute name?

Comment: The obvious question is: why do you want to do this? There's a good chance that it's simply not possible, like jumping off the floor of a falling elevator to save your life.

Comment: This might answer to your question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951686/angular-2-dynamic-two-way-binding

Comment: @Chris G: The obvious answer is: because I need to. That's why I asked on this forum. I need to add a new attribute with that name to a 3rd party element.

Comment: @Y. Tarion: Now, that's a constructive answer. Thank you!

Comment: I simply assume that you are trying to solve a certain problem X, and trying to add an attribute like that is the solution you've come up with. Now that doing this has failed and seems impossible, I'm wondering what X is, so we can suggest an alternative solution.